# Generic Types - Accessing current class in superclass

Tags: java, generics, superclass

I have got two classes. My first one is called "Manager" and is dependent to my second class "ManageAble". This dependence is made through a generic type which is a classparameter as you can see in the code of Manager:

```
public class ManageAble {

 private int id;
 private Manager<?> manager;

 protected ManageAble() {
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 // used by reflection
 private final <T extends ManageAble> void construct(Manager<T> pManager,
        final Integer pID) {
    manager = pManager;
    id = pID;
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 // used by reflection
 private final void deconstruct() {
    manager = null;
    id = -1;
 }

 protected boolean isAttatched() {
    return manager != null;
 }

 public final <T extends ManageAble> Manager<T> getManager() {
    if (manager != null) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Manager<T> castedManager = (Manager<T>) manager;
            return castedManager;
        } catch (ClassCastException pCce) {
            // returns null
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

 public final int getID() {
    return id;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return "[" + id + "] - " + manager;
 }
}
```

The method "register" of the class "Manager" will be called in the constructor of the class "ManageAble". But for that i need to figure out, if my current object is an instance of a class, which can be used as the parameter "pType" in the method "register". Here is the code of "ManagerAble":

```
public class Manager<Type extends ManageAble> {

 private final Map<Integer, Type> managed = new HashMap<Integer, Type>();
 private final Method construct = getManageAbleMethod("construct",
        new Class[] { Manager.class, Integer.class });
 private final Method deconstruct = getManageAbleMethod("deconstruct", null);

 public final boolean isManaging(final ManageAble pEntity) {
    if (pEntity != null) {
        return pEntity.equals(managed.get(pEntity.getID()));
    }
    return false;
 }

 public final boolean detatch(final ManageAble pEntity) {
    if (isManaging(pEntity)) {
        managed.remove(pEntity.getID());
        try {
            Object[] param = null;
            deconstruct.invoke(pEntity, param);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // won't happen
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }

 public final synchronized boolean attatch(final Type pEntity) {
    if (pEntity != null)
        if (!isManaging(pEntity) && !pEntity.isAttatched()) {
            int id = getFreeID();
            managed.put(id, pEntity);
            try {
                construct.invoke(pEntity, new Object[] { this, id });
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException e) {
                // won't happen
            }
            return true;
        }
    return false;
 }

 private final int getFreeID() {
    int id = 0;
    Set<Integer> idsInUse = managed.keySet();
    while (idsInUse.contains(id))
        id++;
    return id;
 }

 private final Method getManageAbleMethod(final String pMethodName,
        final Class<?>[] pParam) {
    try {
        Method m = ManageAble.class.getDeclaredMethod(pMethodName, pParam);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return m;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        return null;
    }
 }
}
```

As you can see, at the place where i insterted the comment instead of a generic type parameter, I don't know how to force the parameter to be the class which defines the constructor.

Is there any way to access the generic type of the current class inside its superclass?

Thanks for help :)

EDIT: I Updated the code to what i got so far. I solved my problem more or less by ugly try/catch and reflection... Any better ideas?

Comment: (Not sure I understood) Are you looking for `Manager<ManageAble>`?

Comment: No. I wan't to write a constructor in my class "ManagerAble" which takes as type-argument for its manager the current class. So if you directly istantinate ManagerAble the generic type shall be ManagerAble. If you instantinate any subclass, the generic type shall be the subclass

Answer (score 0):

I think that to meet your requirements, your `ManageAble` class should also be a generic. Something like

```
public class ManageAble<T>  {

    private final int id;

    protected ManageAble(Manager<? super T> pManager) {
        id = pManager.register((T) this);
    }

    public final int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

Of course, `Manager` would become :

```
public class Manager<Type extends ManageAble<Type>> {
...
```

You can then use it like this :

```
class Foo extends ManageAble<Foo> {

    public Foo(Manager<? super Foo> pManager) {
        super(pManager);
    }
}
```

and

```
Manager<Foo> mg = new Manager<>();
Foo f = new Foo(mg);
```

Comment: I still could do ManageAble<String> and it would destroy the whole construct. I need something safe because it's gonna be an api for sb else. also your cast isn't saved like mine isn't, too. and a safe cast is what i am looking for

Comment: @Basti : No you could not to it directly. Because you have to pass it a Manager and the manager must be constructed for a `class T extends ManageAble<T>` and String does not (directly) extends ManageAble<String> ! So you should first build a ManageAble extending String. Just try it into an IDE ...

Comment: @Basti : I forgot the line for the declaration of the `Manager` class. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yea i already understood the thought of your doing, but i am searching for a save way you can't trick to use the currently operating class as type. I used the way you solved it in one of my older projects, but in my case it isn't a good solution. thank you anyways

Comment: @Basti : you are on your own :-) . I also use those constructs, even if I prefere that one class depends on other, and I avoid cross dependance. But AFAIK, you won't be able to trick it ... If you say what requirement is not met, I could harden the solution.